# how to sort python objects using key of python list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings in the below format:

```
['b-3','a-2','c-4','d-2']
```

Need to sort in such a way that list is sorted by the number (following -). If the numbers are equal, the string needs to be sorted in alphabetical order. Output should be

```
['a-2','d-2','b-3','c-4']
```

I can easily achieve in JAVA using comparator / comparable. How to achieve this by writing the function in python.

```
list.sort(key= )

import sys
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
def sortfunc(item):
    key,value = item.split('-')
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = input().strip()
    c = Counter(s)

    lst = []

    for key in c:
        lst.append(key+'-'+str(c[key]))

    lst.sort(key=lambda x :sortfunc(x), reverse=True)
    print(lst)
```

gives the output as:

```
['b-3', 'c-2', 'a-2', 'e-1', 'd-1']
```

Now, I need help to enhance sortFunc is such as way - if the count of characters are equal, then the string needs to be sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: what have you tried so far? what specific problems are you having with the techniques you've tried?

Comment: You can actually use the `key=` pretty similarly to how you can use the `comparator` in java

Comment: `[b-3,a-2,c-4,d-2]` are not strings, do you mean `['b-3', 'a-2', 'c-4', 'd-2']`?

Comment: @setushwetank, Please see new marked duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way.

```
lst = ['b-3', 'a-2', 'c-4', 'd-2']

res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: (lambda y: (int(y[1]), y[0]))(x.split('-')))

# ['a-2', 'd-2', 'b-3', 'c-4']
```

**Explanation**

- Use `sorted` with `key` argument and a custom `lambda` function.
- Tuple comparisons are performed in order of tuple index.
- Remember to convert the first tuple value to `int` for integer comparison.
- You cannot use `x.split('-')[::-1]` directly as you need to convert one of the values to `int`.

Comment: These downvotes are harsh. If it's because it's a dupe, at least DV the question as well- or leave a comment! I think sometimes people like to jump on the bandwagon. This is a good answer.

Comment: @vaultah, updated with an unhealthy one-liner with single split :).